# Assertion failure in case of boost::lockfree:queue default constructor

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

How can I use `boost::lockfree:queue` objects?

I'm trying to write an application that constructs an object of this class via default constructor, but it gives me an assertion failure inside the boost sources:

```
BOOST_ASSERT(has_capacity);
```

How can I use the default constructor for this class? Do I need to specify the size of the queue via template arguments?

Answer (score 9):

The capacity can be given statically, so it's even **before** the default constructor.

```
boost::lockfree::queue<int, boost::lockfree::capacity<50> > my_queue;
```

The mechanism resembles named parameters for template arguments.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69c3f014e69a758e)**

```
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::lockfree;

struct X { int i; std::string s; };

int main()
{
    queue<int, boost::lockfree::capacity<50> > q;
}
```

Comment: and if I don't want a fixed size queue?

Comment: then you need to pass it to the constructor IIRC (you asked about the template argument method specifically, ... ): `boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue(128);` (e.g. [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the queue's [size_type constructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html#id-1_3_23_6_3_1_1_1_6-bb) instead, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

int main() {

    boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue( 0 );

    int pushed = 4;
    int popped = 0;

    if( queue.push( pushed ) ) {
        std::cout << "Pushed " << pushed << std::endl;
    }

    if( queue.pop( popped ) ) {
        std::cout << "Popped " << popped << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```